# Django export-import admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import a json file to my database with Django export-import extension.
but when I try to import I get this error msg

```
"Line number: 1 - 'id'
20, 2, 1, CONTAINER1134, 26.30, 10, 1, 1, 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/tiberiuminzat/.local/share/virtualenvs/redrock-planning-system-I02kV_z2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 661, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/Users/tiberiuminzat/.local/share/virtualenvs/redrock-planning-system-I02kV_z2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 353, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/Users/tiberiuminzat/.local/share/virtualenvs/redrock-planning-system-I02kV_z2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 340, in get_instance
import_id_fields = [
File "/Users/tiberiuminzat/.local/share/virtualenvs/redrock-planning-system-I02kV_z2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 341, in <listcomp>
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'id'"
```

models.py

```
class Subtask(models.Model):
    subtaskID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    operationID = models.ForeignKey('Operation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    containerID = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    containerWeightT = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    loadSeq = models.IntegerField()
    moveTo = models.ForeignKey('MoveTo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stow = models.ForeignKey('Stow', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        'Status', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

resources.py

```
from import_export import resources
from redrock.models import Subtask

class SubtaskResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Subtask
        import_id_fields = ('subtaskID')
```

admin.py

```
class SubtaskAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['subtaskID', 'operationID','assignee',
                    'containerID', 'containerWeightT', 'loadSeq', 'moveTo', 'stow', 'status']
    list_editable = ['containerID', 'containerWeightT', 'loadSeq', 'status','assignee']
    list_filter = ['operationID', 'status']
    list_per_page = 10

    def status(self, operation):
        return operation.status.status
```

json

```
[{"subtaskID": 20, "operationID": 2, "assignee": 1, 
"containerID": "CONTAINER1134", "containerWeightT": "26.30", 
"loadSeq": 10, "moveTo": 1, "stow": 1, "status": 3}]
```